# DataContract Models in Portable Class Library not extensible?

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer, portable-class-library, iextensibledataobject

I am creating a Portable Class Library targeting .Net 4.5+, Silverlight 5+, and Windows 8+ Store Apps. This library includes Model objects that will be serialized and deserialized into files for transport between implementing applications. While Portable Class Libraries support `DataContractAttribute` and `DataContractSerializer`, they do not support `IExtensibleDataObject` - which is recommended for Forward-Compatible Data Contracts ([MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731083.aspx)).

I am almost certain that the model objects will change over time. What can I do to keep serialization/deserialization with `DataContractSerializer` from failing at the least, but also prevent loss of information in a round-trip operation? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Considering using [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). It appears to work in Portable Class Libraries. Not a fan of having to number the members, but it does allow for change over time it seems.