# protobuf-net Version Tolerance

Tags: serialization, protobuf-net

[Earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339696/datacontract-models-in-portable-class-library-not-extensible)

I was hoping to use [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) in a redistributable library package which will be incorporated in multiple applications. Each application will need to be able to open files that were serialized by the library, manipulate the objects, and then save/serialize back to the file. Of course versioning becomes a big issue here. I do not want to lose data if an older version round-trips a file that was generated from a newer version. Then I found the `ProtoBuf.Extensible` base class, but quickly discovered that `ProtoBuf.IExtensible` does not support classes with inheritance. I absolutely must have inheritance.

Do I have any options here? I'm starting to feel like serialization with version tolerance and anything more than the simplest of classes is a pipe dream.

Answer (score 0):

As with most things: features take effort to design, implement, test, and support. The combination of inheritance and extensible is not something that I've had the need / demand to fully investigate to date. I'm sure it is solve-able, but: it isn't totally trivial. Keep in mind that raw protobuf (the Google specification) doesn't include inheritance at all :p

At the moment, the state is simply "that isn't a supported use-case". There isn't a magic `[MakeItWork]` you can add. It would take some thought etc.

Comment: that's a shame, I love `[MakeItWork]` magic one-liners ;) I'm planning to look at the source tomorrow.

Comment: @Ethan caution: insane amounts of meta-programming. IIRC, `TypeSerializer` is the key type here. The issue here, however, is mainly a design one: how to actually correctly round-trip such data. It could be that the problem is actually the "add extended data" methods - maybe they need a type qualifier (perhaps only in the inheritance case) to indicate at what level that data hypothetically exists.